# cwd evaluated before onlyif in exec - puppet 5.5.12

Tags: puppet

In Puppet 5.5.0 this worked fine, but in Puppet 5.5.12 it does no longer work:

```
exec { 'example' :
    command     =>  "date",
    cwd     =>  "/fu",
    onlyif  =>  "ls /fu",
    path    => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/bin', ],
}
```

Error message:
Could not evaluate: Working directory /fu does not exist!

So somehow cwd is now getting evaluated before the onlyif making the latter futile. Any idea where this comes from in this minor release from 5.5.0 to 5.5.12? 
Is there a bug or intended behavior? I could not find anything so far.

Any input is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behaviour I'm afraid. From https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-cwd:

> **cwd**
>
> The directory from which to run the command. If this directory does not exist, the command will fail.

Could you recode as something like this?

```
exec { 'example' :
    command     =>  "cd /fu && date",
    onlyif  =>  "[ -d /fu ]",
    path    => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/bin', ],
}
```

Comment: Yes, this actually worked! Thanks!

It looks like this is the explanation from https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-onlyif:
Note that this test command runs with the same provider, path, user, and group as the main command. If the path isn’t set, you must fully qualify the command’s name.

So the "cwd" now impacts the path of the "onlyif".

So then intention and documentation has always been the same since 4.10, to 5.5.0, to 5.5.12, but from 5.5.0 to 5.5.12 behavior got changed to match the intention. 

STILL REALLY WEIRD, but ok. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The documentation reference provided does not establish that the observed behavior is intended.  It speaks only to the execution of *the command* (i.e. the `command` parameter), which should not be executed at all if the `onlyif` command fails.

Answer (score 2):

> So somehow cwd is now getting evaluated before the onlyif making the
>   latter futile. Any idea where this comes from in this minor release
>   from 5.5.0 to 5.5.12?

This is Puppet issue [PUP-9194](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-9194), which they claim to be a fix for a regression.  It was reported against Puppet 6, and it is documented in the release notes for Puppet 6.0.2.  The comment thread on the ticket reports that the fix was also applied to the Puppet 5 codebase. No release note seems to have been added in the Puppet 5 series, but the timing is right for Puppet 5.5.7.

> Is there a bug or intended behavior? I could not
>   find anything so far.

Evidently the behavior change was intentional; it is the old behavior that was considered buggy.  I note here that that conclusion seems to be based on historic practice, not documentation (so the behavior you relied upon differed from even older behavior).  The docs for `onlyif` specify several `Exec` attributes that apply both to the main `command` and to `onlyif` commands, and `cwd` is not among them.

Comment: This is very insightful and makes perfect sense. Thank you!